# mysql inner joining & dynamic rank calculation error #1241

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to calculate the rank of the user in my portal... i am joining user name from the `user_table_name` to the `rank_table` and calculating there rank dynamically if i run the query individually it runs fine but when i use it together there is a #1241 error
here is mycode

```
SELECT (SELECT utn.name, rt.amount_left, rt.loan_amount, rt.currency_amount,
               rt.stock_amount, rt.fd_amount, rt.user_money
        FROM `user_table_name` AS utn INNER JOIN
             `rank_table` AS rt on rt.user_id=utn.userid
       ) AS ut, 
       (SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    rank_table ui
        WHERE   (ui.amount_left) >= (uo.amount_left)
       ) AS rank 
FROM    rank_table uo
WHERE   1
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Thanks Gordon for below query

```
SELECT utn.name, rt.amount_left, rt.loan_amount, rt.currency_amount,
   rt.stock_amount, rt.fd_amount, rt.user_money,
   (SELECT  COUNT(*)
     FROM    rank_table ui
     WHERE   (ui.amount_left) >= (rt.amount_left)
   ) AS rank
FROM `user_table_name` utn INNER JOIN
 `rank_table` rt
  on rt.user_id = utn.userid
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

but
the query gives me weird results such as if the 10 and 11 position user have same point then there rank is shows as 11 not 10..so can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery to a `select` can only return one column.  Not a bunch of them.  I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT utn.name, rt.amount_left, rt.loan_amount, rt.currency_amount,
       rt.stock_amount, rt.fd_amount, rt.user_money,
       (SELECT  COUNT(*)
         FROM    rank_table ui
         WHERE   (ui.amount_left) >= (rt.amount_left)
       ) AS rank
FROM `user_table_name` utn INNER JOIN
     `rank_table` rt
      on rt.user_id = utn.userid
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

Comment: the above query gives me weird results such as if the 10 and 11 position user have same point then there rank is shows as 11 not 10..so can you please help

Comment: @AnkitLadhania . . . Change the `>=` to `>` and the `count(*)` to `count(*) + 1`.